# Why is the register length static in any CPU

Tags: performance, comparison, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

Why is the register length (in bits) that a CPU operates on not dynamically/manually/arbitrarily adjustable? Would it make the computer slower if it was adjustable this way?

Imagine you had an 8-bit integer. If you could adjust the CPU register length to 8 bits, the CPU would only have to go through the first 8 bits instead of extending the 8-bit integer to 64 bits and then going through all 64 bits.

Comment: Hardware usually operates on all bits in parallel anyway.  64-bit xor isn't slower than 8-bit xor.  Only a few operations on some CPUs are slower for larger operand-size.  (x86 has variable operand-size, even though the register width is fixed.  See http://agner.org/optimize/ for instruction tables, and look especially at latency/throughput for MUL and DIV (operand-size dependent) vs. almost everything else (constant).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Architectures like ARM (presumably others as well) supports [half precision floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format). The idea is to do what you were speculating and @Margaret explained. With half precision floats, you can pack two float values in a single register, thereby introducing less bandwidth at a cost of reduced accuracy.

Reference:

[[1]](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0774d/chr1421838476257.html) ARM

[[2]](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Half-Precision.html) GCC

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought you were asking if it was possible to have a CPU with no definitive register size. That make no sense since the number and size of the registers is a physical property of the hardware and cannot be changed.

However some architecture let the programmer work on a smaller part of a register or to pair registers.
The x86 does both for example, with `add al, 9` (uses only 8 bits of the 64-bit `rax`) and `div rbx` (pairs `rdx:rax` to form a 128-bit register).
The reason this scheme is not so diffuse is that it comes with a lot of trade-offs.

More registers means more bits needed to address them, simply put: longer instructions.
Longer instructions mean less code density, more complex decoders and less performance.

Furthermore most elementary operations, like the logic ones, addition and subtraction are already implemented as operating on a full register in a single cycle.
Finally, one execution unit can handle only one instruction at a time, we cannot issue eight 8-bit additions in a 64-bit ALU at the same time.
So there wouldn't be any improvement, nor in the latency nor in the throughput.

Accessing partial registers is useful for the programmer to fan-out the number of available registers, so for example if an algorithm works with 16-bit data, the programmer could use a single physical 64-bit register to store four items and operate on them independently (but not in parallel).
The ISAs that have variable length instructions can also benefit from using partial register because that usually means smaller immediate values, for example and instruction that set a register to a specific value usually have an immediate operand that matches the size of register being loaded (though RISC usually sign-extends or zero-extends it).